# How can I pass the multiple Id to PHP with the help of AJAX and display the images which are select by the user?

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, ajax, session

I have more than 100 users in my database and all are displaying with a check box. 
When user click on check box then Id value will pass to PHP with the help of AJAX and it will display the image of the user.

Above statement is working perfectly because I am passing the single id to PHP.

Now the issue is How can I pass the multiple Id to PHP with the help of AJAX and display the images which are select by the user?

If I checked the single Id then it will display the single image, if I select 2 check box then it will display the two images and up to Three.

I think I have to use SESSION and ARRAY.
Would you help me in this?

```
<input type="checkbox" value="<?php echo $id;?>" name="display_id" id="display_id" />
```

**AJAX**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("[type=checkbox]").click(function() {
        var user_id = $(this).val();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "process", // 
            data: 'id=' + user_id,
            success: function(msg) {
                $("#display_id").html("<img src='images/profile/" + msg + "' alt='' />");
            },
            error: function() {
                alert("failure");
            }
        });
    });
});
```

**process**

```
$_SESSION['id_user']=$_POST['id'];
$sql_compare="SELECT * FROM register WHERE Id=".$_SESSION['id_user'];
$compare_query=$conn->query($sql_compare);
if ($compare_query->num_rows > 0) {
    while($userdata12=$compare_query->fetch_assoc()){ 
        $compare_pic=$userdata12['profile_pic'];
    }
}
echo $compare_pic;
exit();
```

Answer (score 0):

First you should do this,

```
arr = [];
$("[type='checkbox']:checked").each(function(){
    arr.push($(this).val());
});
```

Then you should do this,

```
var params = {
  users : arr
};
```

Then your ajax will be,

```
$.ajax({
             type: "POST",
             url: "process", // 
             data:params,
.
.
.
.
```

Now check whether all checked user ids are getting on server side. if yes,

Then fetch all data and return it as response back to ajax.

**EDIT 1**

```
$sql_compare="SELECT * FROM register WHERE Id IN (".implode(',',$_SESSION['id_user']).")";
```

Comment: Wait. I am trying again

Comment: Because I am getting selected Id in PHP but when I am retrieving image from database then it is displaying only one image

Comment: change Id=".$_SESSION['id_user'] to Id IN "implode(',',.$_SESSION['id_user']);

Comment: I am getting syntax error  SELECT * FROM request WHERE Id IN "implode(',',.$_SESSION['users']);

Comment: ".implode(',',.$_SESSION['id_user']); added . to concat that string

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/152742/discussion-between-hybreeder-and-rahul-meshram).